# QGIS - Visibility Analysis fails with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetGeoTransform' "

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, viewshed, visibility

I'm using [Visibility Analysis](http://www.zoran-cuckovic.from.hr/QGIS-visibility-analysis/) plugin to generate cumulative viewshed maps. The base DEM map is created using GRASS GIS (`r.surf.contour`).

I'm running using the following setting below - but have also tweaked things around trying to make it work:

[image: Visibility Analysis]

Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

#### Versions

- QGIS 2.18.28
- Visibility Analysis 0.5.4

#### Error Log

```
 An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetGeoTransform' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\viewshedanalysis.py", line 197, in run
    Algo)
  File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\doViewshed.py", line 356, in Viewshed
    gt=gdal_raster.GetGeoTransform()#daje podatke o rasteru (metadata)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetGeoTransform'


Python version: 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.28 Las Palmas, aa30730ac6 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\Laubwerk\Python
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/user/.qgis2//python
C:/GIS
```